# Alternate to Thread.stop() in Java 8?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8

Is there any way to force a `Thread` to stop under *Java 8*, now that `Thread.stop` has been removed? This includes forcing a thread waiting on a *lock/synchronized/sleep/wait/infinite* loop to stop.

This is intended as part of a *watchdog* for the application which can detect if it has *deadlocked/frozen*, force kill threads and then save the current state to avoid lost information - while there is a high chance of this information being corrupt due to forcing a thread to stop, it's better to have a copy of the possibly incorrect information than to lose it.

Attempting to save this information without stopping the locked up threads is impossible, as saving it will require acquiring locks.

Comment: Can you do this with [shutdown hooks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) to dump core in response to a SIGQUIT instead of trying to identify misbehaving threads within a VM?

Comment: I mean, the real answer is: Fix the code that is causing the problems that makes you need to kill threads.

Comment: `Thread.stop` was removed? What great news, that was one of the most horrible, vile methods ever. In your case: Nobody can force you to acquire locks while saving the data - that will need some refactoring for you sure and it's obviously error prone, but then that's an inherent problem in what you're trying to do.

Comment: @BrianRoach this is a watchdog for when things go wrong. Unfortunately, they do, and previously it was possible to have better behaviour (trying to stop gracefully) than can be done with java 8.

Obviously not deadlocking would be better, but with complex threaded code with up to hundreds of user plugins not designed to be threaded, it seems to be unavoidable.

Comment: They "go wrong" because of bugs and/or a bad design if the only tool you can use to resolve the issue is one you shouldn't have been using and no longer can. Tens of thousands (being conservative) of other pieces of software don't have this problem and it is unlikely you're doing anything particularly unique (few of us are).

Comment: This question contains misinformation: 1. `Thread.stop()` has not been removed; 2. it has been deprecated for a long time, no change in Java 8 in that respect; 3. it has been used all along nevertheless, although less often. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop--

Comment: The only thing that happened is that `Thread.stop(Throwable)` has been disabled (*not* removed!) so it now throws `UnsupportedOperationException` and does not attempt to stop a thread.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Thanks for clearing that up - didn't see your comment until now but I've marked Holger's answer stating the same thing as correct.

I misunderstood the docs after my code using .stop(Throwable) broke, and thought .stop() had been removed too but didn't actually check that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you really need to stop a `Thread` the hard way you may consider that the method [`Thread.stop()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop--) (without providing an arbitrary `Throwable`) still works with Java 8. It will generate a [`ThreadDeath`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadDeath.html) on the stopped thread which can be handled like any other `Error`, despite its unusual name. The only difference is that no stack trace will be printed if `ThreadDeath` is not caught.

---

But beware that this method is deprecated for most of the same reasons than the other `stop` method. It might become unspported in one of the next releases of Java. So it’s still time to think about a plan B…

Comment: Unfortunately the API change isn't documented at all---it just says "deprecated" as before. No mention of `UnsupporteOperationException` at all.

Comment: Well, [it’s easy to overlook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop-java.lang.Throwable-) but at the end of the entire description there’s the small phrase *Throws UnsupportedOperationException*.

Answer (score 11):

Read these articles, they explain it:

1. "Why Are Thread.stop, Thread.suspend, Thread.resume and Runtime.runFinalizersOnExit Deprecated?"
   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html
2. Joshua Bloch: "Effective Java (2nd Edition)", Item 66: Synchronize access to shared mutable data

Joshua Bloch explains how to stop a thread and says this:

> Consider the task of stopping one thread from another. The libraries
>   provide the Thread.stop method, but this method was deprecated long
>   ago because it is inherently unsafe—its use can result in data
>   corruption. Do not use Thread.stop. A recommended way to stop one
>   thread from another is to have the first thread poll a boolean field
>   that is initially false but can be set to true by the second thread to
>   indicate that the first thread is to stop itself.

When using this technique you should handle also synchronization of the boolean field. I don't want to copy too much stuff from Joshua Bloch's book, but you will find everything there and in the official Oracle Java documentation mentioned above.

Comment: You will have hard time stopping a thread in any state. Just FYI.

Comment: The Oracle doc describes I think all the main cases. Also how and when to use `interrupt`.

Answer (score 3):

The right way to stop a thread is to call `interrupt` on it.

Comment: It should be noted that this is not even close to the same as calling `Thread.stop()` though.  Using `interrupt` assumes the work being done in the thread is well behaved and interruptible.  That's not the case with something as simple as blocking on an `InputStream`, and thus is not likely sufficient for a watchdog.

Comment: @MarkPeters I didn't say it's the same as calling stop. I said it's the correct way to stop/kill (name it as you wish) a thread.

Comment: But it doesn't stop or kill a thread.  It sets a bit on a thread that, if the blocking operation is interruptible, will throw an exception which the running code can catch and ignore however it wants.  It's a signalling mechanism that many/most blocking operations don't actually listen to.

Comment: I think it would be more correct to say that the right way to have a thread stop is for the thread to terminate itself when interrupted for a stop

Comment: If the thread isn't listening to my commands, would I be a terrible person for issuing a kill order? :(

Comment: @MxyL Only `Thread#stop` is a far cry from a kill order... a simple `catch (Throwable t) {}` dodges it.

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1:**

```
yourThreadObj.interrupt()
```

**Step 2: Override interrupt() method in your thread class and stop your operations by this boolean**

```
public class SampleLooperThread extends Thread{

private boolean isInterrupted= false;
@Override
public void run() {
   
      if(isInterrupted){
           // stop your blocks
      }
   //your blocks of code 


}

@Override
public void interrupt() {
    super.interrupt();
    isInterrupted = true;
}
}
```